# Where are my options in Safari Share menu

Tags: safari, macos

This is a typical share menu:

[image]

For an unknown reason, mine looks like this:

[image]

How can I recover all others missing options?

This is what I get when I hit on more:

[image]

After the last update of OS X Yosemite to Version 10.10.2 (14C81f) the issue seems fixed, but only for one day. Then all options gone again.

Comment: What happens when you click on "More"?