# How to restore default sharing extension under Yosemite

Tags: macos, sharing

OS X Yosemite introduce few extensions like sharing extensions. With some defaults one like share with Apple Mail, iMessage, ... but today thoses extensions are missing for me. Is there's any knowed way, even with CLI to restaure them ?

[image: missing defaults sharing options]

Comment: I asked the same a few time ago without answers: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161513/where-are-my-options-in-safari-share-menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -seed`