# Safari (and system) share menu - Messages and other items missing in Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, safari, macos, sharing

## System configuration

- Running Sierra (10.12.5)
- MacBook Pro 13" (Early 2015)

## Issue

#### Messages and many other options are missing from the system Share menu, both in Safari and in the Share Menu extensions pane.

[image]

### These among others are missing:

- Messages (most annoying)
- Facebook
- Twitter
- Linkedin
- Vimeo
- Flickr

## Here's what I've tried so far with no success:

- Update to latest Sierra 10.12.5
- Run [this command line](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167463/how-to-restore-default-sharing-extension-under-yosemite) to force-reload launch services
- Disable and re-enable iCloud contacts
- Disable and reenable System Integrity Protection

## Related observations

- Under Preferences -> Internet Accounts, I cannot check the box next to 'Share Menu' for Facebook, Twitter, Vimeo etc, even though accounts are correctly configured.
  [image]

Really appreciate any help!

### Update 7/11:

I just got an old 2011 MackBook Pro repaired, and upgraded it from El Capitan to Sierra. The Share menu works as expected, with Messages as an option. Still not working on the machine with the problem.

Comment: I should mention that all the social accounts (facebook, twitter, etc) are correctly configured in the Internet Accounts preference pane.

Comment: I just got an old 2011 MackBook Pro repaired, and upgraded it from El Capitan to Sierra. The Share menu works as expected, with Messages as an option.

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203129
This is the fix according to apple. I have a very similar problem but this fix enabled only one or two extensions for me. I ran it 3 times. I'm still looking for more info

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks, looking back at my OP I see that I tried this with no success. I just tried it again and it actually _reduced_ the number of services appearing in the sharing menu. Messages, Twitter, Facebook etc still will not appear.

Comment: Update: reinstalling MacOS High Sierra from the App Store did not resolve this.

Answer (score -1):

After running the lsregister command from the link I had to log out and log back in again for the share menu to change.